# renaming network interface with systemd

Tags: networking, fedora, systemd

I want to rename on Fedora 22 a network interface managed by systemd-networkd (version 219) from the system-assigned name `enp2s0` into `wan`. For that I created the following file `/etc/systemd/network/80-wan.link`:

```
[Match]
MACAddress=mac-address
[Link]
Name=wan
```

However, that have no effect on the system. After rebooting the name is still `enp2s0`. I see with `udevadm` that udev picked up the file for configuration but ignored the supplied name:

```
~> udevadm info /sys/class/net/enp2s0 
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
E: ID_BUS=pci
E: ID_MM_CANDIDATE=1
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
E: ID_MODEL_ID=0x8168
E: ID_NET_DRIVER=r8169
E: ID_NET_LINK_FILE=/etc/systemd/network/80-wan.link
E: ID_NET_NAME_MAC=enxMacAddress
E: ID_NET_NAME_PATH=enp2s0
E: ID_OUI_FROM_DATABASE=Shuttle Inc.
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:02:00.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_02_00_0
E: ID_PCI_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Network controller
E: ID_PCI_SUBCLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Ethernet controller
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0x10ec
E: IFINDEX=2
E: INTERFACE=enp2s0
E: SUBSYSTEM=net
E: SYSTEMD_ALIAS=/sys/subsystem/net/devices/enp2s0
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=24183
```

Also there is no mentioning of the new name `wan` in any logs even after activating udev debugging output. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At least on Debian stretch, it seems like you need to `update-initramfs -u && reboot` for `*.link` files in `/etc/systemd/network/` to take effect for existing interfaces.

It seems like the network interfaces get renamed very early during boot from within the initramfs, before the `*.link` files in `/etc/systemd/network` are available... and once the interface has been renamed once (`/sys/class/net/*/name_assign_type=4`), then the the [`udev-builtin-net_setup_link`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/8d93d7d84ba5900106243693a90244bb59d93f2b/src/udev/udev-builtin-net_setup_link.c) will no longer [emit `ID_NET_NAME`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/8d93d7d84ba5900106243693a90244bb59d93f2b/src/udev/udev-builtin-net_setup_link.c#L48) [because](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/3e010e3baf06a83d9526d77ad35aa560e29c1ff2/src/udev/net/link-config.c#L438) [`should_rename` returns `false`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/3e010e3baf06a83d9526d77ad35aa560e29c1ff2/src/udev/net/link-config.c#L316).

Comment: It's the same situation on Ubuntu 18.04 (and probably later too). Thanks for the fix.

Comment: I tried running 'dracut -f' in Fedora to rebuild the initramfs and rebooted, but this didn't solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 7):

Are you using `systemd-networkd`? I think the `.link` files are only relevant if you are (instead of the default NetworkManager or legacy initscripts). (I admit I haven't looked deeply into it yet, though.)

I think what you want is a `.rules` file in `/etc/udev/rules.d`, something like

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="mac-address", NAME="wan"
```

(where `mac-address` is your actual hex MAC address, of course).

This file needs to be ordered *before* `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules`, so the [upstream docs](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) suggest `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-my-net-names.rules`.

Comment: Yes, I use systemd-networkd. Its [docs](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html) gives an example of renaming and I do not see why my case does not work.

Comment: In those same docs, you can also see that you can override the udev config by having a link file before debian's or your own distro's 99-default.link.  YMMV here, filename-wise.

This doesn't appear to be the issue of the OP but for anyone else landing here, make sure your link filename starts with a number lower than 9.  Something like 10-eth.link

Answer (score 3):

For some bad reasons it seems that networkmanager has priority over networkd(who could imagine that?). You can test this as follows:

- `systemctl stop NetworkManager`
- unplug the network interface
- `ip addr`

Result: /etc/systemd/network/*.link rules are honored

If you start NetworkManager and repeat the test /etc/systemd/network/*.link is not honored anymore. I tested this with the `MACAddressPolicy=random` directive