# What is the equivalent of Ubuntu /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ in Fedora (22)

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, fedora

I'm trying to migrate from Ubuntu to Fedora(22) but I can't find how to run a network script before the interface is up. Is there any equivalent of this /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ in Fedora?

I need to trigger a script whenever an (any) interface is up and catch the interface in a variable (so that I can execute macchanger on it). 
  Initially I thought this can be managed with systemd-networkd but seems it's not the case when NetworkManager is active[1]

[0] https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AnonymizingNetworkMACAddresses

[1] https://superuser.com/a/948996/412798

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the script must be placed in networkmanager dispatcher. The path may be "/usr/local/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/pre-up.d/macchanger" or "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/pre-up.d/macchanger". Compared with the Ubuntu tutorial you must use the first argument ( $1 ) istead of $IFACE.

```
#!/bin/bash
ip link set dev $1 down
macchanger -e "$1"
ip link set dev $1 up
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been runnig some tests and the only way that worked for me was with a systemd unit:

`vim /etc/systemd/system/macspoof@[your-interface].service`

```
[Unit]
Description=macchanger on %I
Wants=network-pre.target
Before=network-pre.target
BindsTo=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/macchanger -r %I
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

change the permissions to 755

`chmod 755 /etc/systemd/system/macspoof@[your-interface].service`

then enable the service

`systemctl enable macspoof@[your-interface].service`

check this link for more information: [MAC address spoofing](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MAC_address_spoofing)

Comment: This throws `Failed to get properties: Access denied. ` I think `vim /etc/systemd/system/macspoof@[your-interface].service` is incorrect. It should be `/etc/systemd/system/macspoof@.service` but it's not working anyway. Are you sure you tested this?

Comment: the idea is to use the name of your interface, for example `macspoof@eth0.service`. In my case I've used `macspoof@wlp3s0.service` and it worked fine

Comment: Note that systemd service files do not need to be executable (they don't have a shebang so trying to execute them will not work anyway). You likely don't need to `chmod` them, but if you do, it would be more appropriate to set the mode to 644, not 755.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/pre-up.d/

Comment: I already added the macchanger script to `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/pre-up.d/` and chmod +x  but the mac is not changed